# Outputting foreign characters in PHP?

Tags: php

I have a number of foreign characters in A MYSQL database:

```
ü
```

They come out on the site like:

```
Ã¤
```

I can't convert them on database entry as I import a spreadsheet from client to make the table.

Is there a way in php to make them output correctly?

Thanks!

Comment: add the correct [charset](http://nl.wikibooks.org/wiki/HTML/Character_sets) in your HTML file

Answer (score 2):

It's either because your document encoding is wrong or your database link is not UTF-enabled.

What editor are you using?

Also make sure you have the correct charset set in the head of your page by adding this meta tag:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF8" />
```

Comment: How do I make my database link UTF enabled?

Answer (score 0):

use `utf8_encode` function it will help you.

Comment: He should't do that. If the charset is set, the file encoding is correct and the database connection uses the same encoding, he wont have to.